# Split implementation across multiple files/modules and keep everything as private as possible

Tags: module, rust, private, public

Consider the following code in my library:

```
pub struct Foo;
impl Foo {
    fn helper(&self) { /* .. */ }
}

pub fn do_something(foo: &Foo) {
    foo.helper();
}
```

The users of my library should be able to use `Foo` and `do_something()`, but shall *never* call `helper()`. Everything works fine with the code above. But now imagine the code gets huge and I want to separate those definitions into their own files/modules -- they are then pulled back into the root-namespace with `pub use`. See here:

```
mod foo {  // module contents in `src/foo.rs`
    pub struct Foo;
    impl Foo {
        fn helper(&self) { /* .. */ }
    }    
}

mod do_something {  // module contents in `src/do_something.rs`
    use super::Foo;
    pub fn do_something(foo: &Foo) {
        foo.helper();
    }
}

pub use foo::Foo;
pub use do_something::do_something;
```

Now the compiler complains that `helper()` is private. Indeed it is, but I still want `do_something()` be able to use it. But I don't want my users to use it. How can I do that?

My attempted solution boils down to "How to access private items of sibling modules?". So answering that question would help me. But providing an alternative solution/a workaround would also be great!

Comment: There is an RFC (https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1422) now in Final Comment Period for adding more fine-grained control of visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [Rust 1.18](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/06/08/Rust-1.18.html), you can use the `pub(crate)` syntax to expose something throughout your entire crate but not outside of it:

```
mod foo {  // module contents in `src/foo.rs`
    pub struct Foo;
    impl Foo {
        pub(crate) fn helper(&self) { /* .. */ }
    }    
}
```

All the possibilities, as suggested by the compiler, include:

- `pub(crate)`: visible only on the current crate
- `pub(super)`: visible only in the current module's parent
- `pub(in path::to::module)`: visible only on the specified path

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a cargo project with a file structure like this:

```
src\lib.rs
src\foo\mod.rs
src\foo\do_something.rs
src\bin\test.rs
```

`test.rs` is just to demonstrate that it works as intended for users of the library.

In src\lib.rs:

```
mod foo;

pub use foo::*;
```

In src\foo\mod.rs:

```
mod do_something;

pub use self::do_something::*;

pub struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn helper(&self) { /* .. */ }
}
```

In src\foo\do_something.rs:

```
use super::Foo;
pub fn do_something(foo: &Foo) {
    foo.helper();
}
```

In src\bin\test.rs

```
extern crate mylibname;
use mylibname::*;

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo;
    do_something(&foo);
    // foo.helper(); //Uncommenting gives an error.
}
```

This compiles for me.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough: `Foo` and it's impl also live in their own module/file (`src/foo.rs`). Will update my question accordingly.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Child modules can access the parent's private items. But here's an updated example anyway.

Comment: Yes, but it's not about accessing the parent's items, but about accessing the sibling's items. The modules `foo` and `do_something` are on the same level == are siblings.

Comment: I will edit my question a lot to make it easier to understand.